# How can I compare the schema of objects in SQL server that belong to two different schemas?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2013, database-schema

I have a table under dbo and an almost identical table under a schema called tmp. Visual Studio Schema Compare does not appear to let me select one set of dbo-based objects and compare them with a similar set of tmp-based objects.

The database server is locked down and it is not possible to create a second database. Also, SQL server is unusable on a local dev machine due to resource constraints. The tmp schema would allow me to make changes to tmp, then compare and push those changes to the dev schema of "dbo".

What's the best way to compare these two sets of objects?

Comment: This is likely to get closed as being off-topic for being either opinion based or suggesting a resource. Have you looked SQL Compare from RedGate? It can do this right out the box with ease.

Comment: I don't know why you have posted this question because the answer is obvious. if you have only one table, you can generate script and then compare it. if not you can google free database comparison tool. This is a good one: http://dbcomparer.com/

Answer (score 7):

You can compare your objects with different schemas with [ApexSQL Diff](https://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_diff.aspx) and it has free Community edition.

By creating custom schema mapping, you’ll be able to match objects with different schemas compare them and synchronize if needed.

If you just want to compare objects to see differences and create a merge script, you can check out a free tool - [ApexSQL Compare](https://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_compare.aspx).

Since RedGate tool is already mentioned, one more tool that can help you out is [dbForge Schema Compare](https://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/schemacompare/ordering.html).

Answer (score 4):

Two methods come to mind. Try redgates sql-compare tool, worth its weight in gold imo.

Another option would be to use the 'generate scripts' functionality of ssms and then use the diff tool of your choice to compare the resultant sql text files.